# Adding Pagination to to custom form block results

Tags: 7, forms, paging

I have created a custom block that has a form which has a list of result and I wanted to know how to add pagination to the results

Thanks for any help on this

Colin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    /**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function custommodule_block_info() {
    $blocks = array();
    $blocks['latest_news'] = array(
        'info' => t('Latest News'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );

    return $blocks;
}

    /**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function custommodule_block_view($delta = '') {
    $block = array();
    switch ($delta) {

        case 'latest_news':
            $block['subject'] = t('');
            $block['content'] = latest_news();
            break;
    }
    return $block;
}


/*
 * Implementation of hook_theme
 * */

function custommodule_theme() {
    return array(

        'latest_news' => array('variables' => array('data' => array()),
        'template' => 'latest_news'),

    );
}

    function latest_news() {
     $query = db_select('node', 'node');
    $query = $query->fields('node', array('nid'))
            ->condition('node.status', 1) //Published.
            ->condition('node.type', 'auction_news');
    $query = $query->extend('PagerDefault');
    $result = $query->limit(20)->orderBy('node.created', 'DESC')->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $paging = theme('pager');

    return theme('latest_news',array('data' => $result,'paging'=>$paging));
}
```

In a tpl file latest_news.tpl.php

```
 <ul>

    <?php 
    foreach($data as $lat_news)
    {


       echo '<li>'.$lat_news->nid.'</li>';
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
    <div><?php echo $paging;?></div>
```