# How to add pagination in a block created from a custom module?

Tags: paging

I have made a very simple block that displays an array of strings as a list. I am achieving this by implementing hook_block_view() in my .module file. Right now the list displays ok, but I would like to paginate it so that only a few list items show at a time.

I am not getting the list from a database, I just have an array of strings as I mentioned before. I have been looking at theme_pager functions, but I am not sure how to use them to do what I need. Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Edit:
I have found the following code here ([Adding Pagination to to custom form block results](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/121912/adding-pagination-to-to-custom-form-block-results)) and I am having trouble making sense of this part of it:

`function latest_news() {
     $query = db_select('node', 'node');
     $query = $query->fields('node', array('nid'))
            ->condition('node.status', 1) //Published.
            ->condition('node.type', 'auction_news');
     $query = $query->extend('PagerDefault');
     $result = $query->limit(20)->orderBy('node.created','DESC')>execute()>fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $paging = theme('pager');
     return theme('latest_news',array('data' => $result,'paging'=>$paging));
}`

Could someone please explain how this part could be modified to use a simple list of strings instead of a database query? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You are using drupal7 or 8.I am assuming you are using drupal7
This link will help for you https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/121912/adding-pagination-to-to-custom-form-block-results

Comment: @sivani Thank you very much! I had seen that question before, but I had not been able to make sense of the part of it that I included in the edit to the question. Maybe you can help me understand the difference between the database query and the list of strings I have?